# python implementation for shadow removal

Tags: python, computer-vision, shadow-removal

I am wondering if there are any python implementation of shadow removal of an image. I have searched online, and there are no existing resources related to python. Or can anyone give me any suggestions.

If you are voting down this question, please give me some reason so I can improve my question.

Appreciate!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are lots of methods to remove shadows.
Using threshold or histogram equalization.
Some other method has not been implemented in the opencv.

Comment: There are lots of methods to remove shadows does not seem to answer the question of a python implementation.

Comment: the answer is there not much python implementation.